# PHP - Always need to fill in the blank in form validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am trying to implement some javascript form validation. I am trying to test for empty field in the form and using an alert to warn users but it is not work for me When i submit full-filled form, it keeps on asking me to fill in the blank.

here is my coding. hope that someone can trace the errors. maybe there are a lot of errors that i don't understand. thank you so much

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <h1 align="center">REGISTRATION

    <br>
    <font style="font-size:20px">Vendor's Information</font></h1>
    <div style="padding-left: 225px">
    <br>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function form_validate()
    {
      with(document.form1)
      {
      if(VENDOR_NAME.value.empty( )) 
      {
        alert("Please fill in the vendor's name");
        VENDOR_NAME.focus();
        VENDOR_NAME.value="";
        return false;
      }
       if(VENDOR_PHONENUM.value.match( )) 
       {
        alert("Please fill in the vendor's contact number");
        VENDOR_PHONENUM.focus();
        VENDOR_PHONENUM.value="";
        return false;
       }
       if(VENDOR_PIC.value.match( )) 
       {
        alert("Please fill in the vendor's person in-charge");
        VENDOR_PIC.focus();
        VENDOR_PIC.value="";
        return false;
       }
       return true;
     }

     }
    </script>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="vendor_registration.php" onSubmit="return form_validate()">
    <font face="Verdana">

    <table border="0">
    <tr style="font-size:15px">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>: <input name="VENDOR_NAME" type="text" size="50"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-size:15px">
        <td>Phone No. </td>
        <td>: <input name="VENDOR_PHONENUM" type="text" size="50"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-size:15px">
        <td>Person In-Charge</td>
        <td>: <input name="VENDOR_PIC" type="text" size="50"><br></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </font>
    <br/><br/>
    <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size: 15px;" >
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="font-size: 15px;">
    </p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try checking console of your browser for any error details

Comment: Use length instead of empty.
So if length == 0, you can fire empty event

Comment: Your form is probably not even submitted... work on that JS validation, or leave it out, because there's no PHP code in here to go on. All there is to see is some (and I'm sorry) terrible JS code. What are you expecting to be the result of `VENDOR_PIC.value.match( )`?

Answer (score 2):

Try Simple validation for emplty field checking,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function form_validate()
    {
      with(document.form1)
      {
      if(VENDOR_NAME.value == '') 
      {
        alert("Please fill in the vendor's name");
        VENDOR_NAME.focus();
        return false;
      }
       if(VENDOR_PHONENUM.value == '') 
       {
        alert("Please fill in the vendor's contact number");
        VENDOR_PHONENUM.focus();
        return false;
       }
       if(VENDOR_PIC.value == '') 
       {
        alert("Please fill in the vendor's person in-charge");
        VENDOR_PIC.focus();
        return false;
       }
       return true;
     }

     }
    </script>
```

Comment: @Dave Thank u, dave. i've run your code but but the problem is still there. maybe there's something wrong with the process code. huhu help~ i'll post the process code

Answer (score 0):

`

```
    include 'db_connect.php';
    $query = "INSERT INTO vendor(VENDOR_NAME, VENDOR_PHONENUM, VENDOR_PIC)
              VALUES ('$VENDOR_NAME', '$VENDOR_PHONENUM', '$VENDOR_PIC')";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    if($result) 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful!'); </script>";
        $url = 'vendor_view.php';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';

        /*echo "<script>alert (\"Registration Successful\")</script>";*/
        /*header('Location: vendor_view.php');*/
    }
    else
        /*echo "<script>alert (\"Registration Failed\")</script>";*/
        echo "<script>alert('Registration Failed!'); </script>";

}
```

?>`